# How to align centre a custom label in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

See [a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mudBorn/F2erm/94/)

```
 labels: {
        items : [{
            html : 'Center Me!',
            style : {
                left : '0px',
                top : '-15px',
                fontSize : '20px'
            }
        }]
    }
```

I am trying to align the custom label in the /labels/items JSON element to hang right under the title and subtitle.

Playing with firebug I can alter the SVG text element for the label and add text-align='middle' and change the x='' attribute to have the same value as the title's x attribute. This makes it perfectly align under the title and stay there when resized but I can't figure out how to make the highcharts library generate this source.

Maybe there is a better way to add another label under the subtitle?

Comment: Which "the custom label" are you talking about? axis label, point label, your own label, ... Where is it? Can you make it more clear?

Comment: First time using jsfiddle and it looks like I didn't' save my changes properly.  Have a look again at the link above and you should see how I am adding the label.  I did take a quick dive into the js for highcharts and it looks like they require an absolute left and top position.  But maybe I missed something?  Anyway, for now, I have just redesigned my title and subtitle so I don't need the other label.  Here is a snippet. `labels: {
        items : [{
            html : 'Center Me!',
            style : {
                left : '0px'`...

Comment: You are right, labels requires top and left properties in pixels to be set. Redesign title+subtitle was a good idea. Another solution may be to use `renderer.text()`, there also you need to set top and left, but this may be done after chart is rendered, to you can calculate position before (using `chart.plotTop`, `chart.plotLeft` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix: Add this to you style

left: '160px'

Answer (score 0):

If you wish, you could also add an HTML element after the chart has been generated to do this effect (see example at http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/5517s8zb/1/).

In this case, to get the proper centered effect, you'll need to explicitly define the container div's width.

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 100%"></div>
```

Here is the HTML element:

```
/* add an HTML element to the chart starting at 0px from the left corner and 
   10% of the container's height from the top */
chart.renderer.html('<div align="center" style="font-size: 20px; width: ' + 
$('#container').width() + 'px">Center Me!</div>',0,$('#container').height()*.1).add();
```

I did the 10% of the container's height to help make the position more flexible. You could also choose to add or subtract specific pixel dimensions until you get it placed where you like.

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score -1):

I used percetange  instead.

```
           left:300%
```

Check this jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F2erm/146/